# m2eclipse can't find any dependencies

Tags: maven, dependencies, m2eclipse

I have created a new Maven project in eclipse, using the Nexus Indexer Archetype.

I am trying to add dependencies to this project via Maven -> Add Dependency. But whenever I search for anything, no dependencies are found.

I have tried setting my Maven -> Installations, to both Embedded and to External (where External points to my M2_HOME directory), but no results from either.

Comment: Have you set your M2_HOME / M2_REPO path in eclipse?

Comment: I have got my M2_HOME set to my Maven install bin directory and M2_REPO set to User/.m2/repository.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Indigo Service Release 1
Build id: 20110916-0149

And version 1.0.1 of m2eclipse

Comment: None, go straight through. Can connect to software update sites through eclipse.